# conditionals inside SQLAlchemy's column_property

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy to map a class:

```
class Model(sqlalchemy.declarative_base()):
    attr_a = Column(String)
    attr_b = Column(Integer)
    attr_c = Column(Integer)

    aggr = column_property(attr_b + attr_c IF attr_a=='go' ELSE attr_b - attr_c)
```

Last line is pseoudo code that requires some conditional logic. Is such logic even possible inside column_property? How can I implement it as a simple conditional aggregate?

Comment: Not sure here, but you might need to create a trigger that fires before insert to populate aggr. Here's a link to creating triggers: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/ddl.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it turns out to be a common technique, sqlalchemy provides a tool set inside `sqlalchemy.sql`, one can easily write SQL logic such as case:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import case

...

aggr = column_property(case([(attr_a=="go", attr_b + attr_c), (attr_a=="return", attr_b + attr_c + attrition]
```

Just note here that `case` takes a python iterable as parameter.